# Grails oauth plugin: Unknown provider linkedin, check your configuration

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-controller

**How to get Connected With Linked In Grails ??**

Config.groovy

```
oauth {
    linkedin {
        requestTokenUrl="https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken"
        accessTokenUrl="https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken"
        authUrl="https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"
        consumer.key="xxx"
        consumer.secret="xxx"
    }
}
```

plugin:

```
compile ":oauth:2.1.0"
```

And GSP :

```
  <oauth:connect provider="linkedin">Connect</oauth:connect>
```

But I trying to run this code.. on browser its showing this error

**`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException`**

**`Tag [oauthLink] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [oauth taglib](http://aiten.github.io/grails-oauth-scribe/guide/usingThePlugin.html) to create button to connect with linkedin rather than g tag

```
<oauth:connect provider="linkedin">Connect</oauth:connect>
```

**EDIT...................................................................................**

Following is my Config.groovy

```
oauth {
  providers {
    linkedin {
        api = org.scribe.builder.api.LinkedInApi
        key = 'xxx'
        secret = 'yyy'

        callback = "http://localhost:8080/test2/oauth/linkedin/callback"
        successUri = "http://localhost:8080/test2/oauthCallBack/linkedin"

        failureUri = "http://localhost:8080/test2/oauthCallBack/linkedinFailure"

        requestTokenUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken"
        accessTokenUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken"
        authUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"
    }
  }
}

grails.linkedin.api.url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,date-of-birth)?format=json"
```

and I have a OauthCallBackController with an action linkedin

```
def linkedin() {
    Token linkedinAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('linkedin')]
    def linkedInResponse = oauthService.getLinkedInResource(linkedinAccessToken, grailsApplication.config.grails.linkedin.api.url)
    def linkedinParsedResponse = JSON.parse(linkedInResponse?.getBody())

    User user = User.findByLinkedInId(linkedinParsedResponse['id'])
    if (user) {
        springSecurityService.reauthenticate(user.username)
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

def linkedinFailure() {
    render "I am back..,."
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. from this error was resolved.. but new error comes :(.. i updated my question

Comment: sorry i asking so many questions.. but this time.. its authicate but... not coming back to my page

Comment: OauthCallBackController is my controller it is used in callback. When linkedin successfully authenticate the user then OauthCallBackController's linkedin method is called as mentioned in config `successUri = "${grails.serverURL}/oauthCallBack/linkedin"`

Comment: Give your page url in successUri in config and after authentication that page is displayed.

Comment: yup i gave but still..its still at linked in authorized page

Comment: Have you given the callback url of your app in the linkedin.

Comment: i gave.. but how to get all the data from linked in.. i put your linked in code.. but its gives me an error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36902/discussion-between-user2446714-and-user1690588)